# Activating a process automatically when the application is not running

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, automation

I'm working on program which rergisters and processes service calls. I'm working in asp.net c# and my data base is on SqL Server. Each call has a status, at first 'NEW' and when work has started on it becomes 'UNDER CARE' and when work is finished 'CLOSED'. After the day is finished in the middle of the night when the application is not running, I want an automatic summing up to be made of the number of calls of the different types of status. How can this be done thru the application or thru the server or any other way even though the application isn't running?

Comment: The simplest solution would be a small console app with your required logic that gets triggerd by a Task on the server http://windows.microsoft.com/nl-NL/windows7/Schedule-a-task

Comment: @RemusRusanu Microsft.com is 'helping' me by forcing me to my native language. I try to be carefull but I missed that one. Here is the more understandable link: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task

Comment: @rene Thank you that is helpful. I had it translated thru the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is a [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) [job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx) [scheduled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320.aspx) to run at midnight.